# .NET dependency and XNA

Tags: c#, linker, xna, dependencies

We have an existing PC game that uses C# and the XNA Framework.  We need to submit this to various Game Portals such as Big Fish Games, who have a stipulation that the .exe provided does not have ANY other dependencies.

We previously had some mileage using tools either the Salamander or RemoteSoft linker tools - I forget which it was 2-3 years ago and I don't have access to that code repository.

Is there another tool out there that will do the same to our XNA application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you're looking for is called [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) or you can try [embedding a dll](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) as a resource. The former changes the assemblies, I believe, while the latter doesn't.

Comment: Great.  Given that ILMerge is from Microsoft, I don't understand why they don't just make it an option in the linker. Whichever method gets me a single install with ZERO other dependencies will be fine.  Can you point me in the direction of a good tutorial?

Comment: There's not that much to it, since it's just a command line. The doc details the full commands, but you might simple use something like "ilmerge /t:winexe /out:MergedGame.exe CompiledGame.exe xna.dll ..." using the proper file names of course. Just be sure the out isn't both the same name and location as the compiled one.